# How to swipe right to hide delete button in UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I currently have my UITableView revealing the "Delete" button when you swipe left on a table view cell.  I want to hide this button with a swipe right on that same cell.  It should be sticky too so that it hides as I swipe right - just like how it reveals the "Delete" button as you swipe left.  Right now, when I swipe left to reveal the delete button, I can only get it to hide when I scroll my table view.  Is there a built-in way to achieve this swipe-right-to-hide behavior?  Or does this need to be a custom built solution?

**EDIT:  I thought the defualt Messages app had this behavior, but I realized that when I was swiping right, I was scrolling the tableview a little bit which caused it to hide.  The only way to hide right now is tapping the cell or scrolling the tableview**

I've set up my tableView to show the delete button by implementing the following method:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   if editingStyle == .delete {
        print("deleted!")
   }     
}
```

Comment: Can share screenshot? how the output will be ?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I too was having an issue trying to allow users to swipe away the Delete option.  (Similar to how Apple's Mail app works)

The only way I found it to work as expected was if you also include a leadingSwipeAction...  (If the user initially swipes either right or left they get different options).  Once you add the other side, then users can swipe the Delete away.

*Incidentally "Swipe the Delete Away" sounds like a dope emo song.*

Here is code I currently have that is almost working perfectly. There is an occasional graphical anomaly with the leading button jumping to the right, but I think that might be due to some other code in my view.  This code is borrowed heavily from https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/uitableview-swipe-actions-in-ios-11/

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {

    if indexPath.section == Slider.Section.results.rawValue {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                        leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration?
{

    let favoriteAction = self.contextualToggleFavoriteAction(forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)

    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [favoriteAction])

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {


    let delete = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive,
                                    title: "Delete") { (contextAction: UIContextualAction, sourceView: UIView, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) in

                                        Filter.allMarkers.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                                        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
                                        completionHandler(true)

    }

    let share = UIContextualAction(style: .normal,
                                    title: "Share") { (contextAction: UIContextualAction, sourceView: UIView, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) in

                                        print("About to share -> \(Filter.allMarkers[indexPath.row].title ?? "")")
                                        completionHandler(true)

    }

    share.backgroundColor = Color.ocean

    let swipeConfig = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete, share])
    return swipeConfig
}


func contextualToggleFavoriteAction(forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction {

    let marker = Filter.allMarkers[indexPath.row]
    let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal,
                                    title: "Favorite") { (contextAction: UIContextualAction, sourceView: UIView, completionHandler: (Bool) -> Void) in
                                        if marker.toggleFavoriteFlag() {
                                            completionHandler(true)
                                        } else {
                                            completionHandler(false)
                                        }
    }

    //action.image = UIImage(named: "flag")
    action.backgroundColor = marker.isFavorite ? Color.magenta : UIColor.gray
    return action
}
```